# error in my Navigation. PushAsync (new DetailsPage (monkey))

Tags: xamarin

I'm following the following example of carousel with the listview, more when I go to open Navigation.PushAsync the item in the listview is called only the first item, on all items clicked his name only the first item, a position error?

```
    void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        var monkey = ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem as Monkey;

        if (monkey == null)
            return;

        Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(monkey));
    }
```

https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/

EDIT

MonkeysPage.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Monkeys.Views.MonkeysPage"
    xmlns:design="clr-namespace:Monkeys;assembly=Monkeys"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
    xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
        BindingContext="{x:Static design:ViewModelLocator.MonkeysViewModel}"
    x:Name="MonkeysPage"
    Title="Traditional Monkeys">
<ContentPage.Content>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MonkeysGrouped}"
            ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            GroupShortNameBinding = "{Binding Key}"
            IsGroupingEnabled = "true"
            GroupDisplayBinding = "{Binding Key}">
     <ListView.Header>
      <cv:CarouselView x:Name="CarouselZoos" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Zoos, Source={x:Reference MonkeysPage}}" HeightRequest="200">
        <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
              <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Padding="12">
                  <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      </cv:CarouselView>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <controls:CircleImage
                   BorderColor="Aqua"
                   BorderThickness="3"
                   HeightRequest="66"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                   WidthRequest="66"
                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   VerticalOptions="End"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   VerticalOptions="Start"
                   Text="{Binding Location}"/>
          </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

MonkeysPage.xaml.cs

```
  public MonkeysPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MonkeysViewModel();
    }


    async void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var monkey = e.SelectedItem as Monkey;

        if (monkey == null)
            return;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(monkey)); // always await Navigations
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

DetailsPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="Monkeys.Views.DetailsPage"
    xmlns:design="clr-namespace:Monkeys;assembly=Monkeys"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
    BindingContext="{x:Static design:ViewModelLocator.DetailsViewModel}"
    Title="{Binding Monkey.Name}">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <controls:CircleImage 
                    BorderColor="Aqua"
                    BorderThickness="3"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    WidthRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                    Source="{Binding Monkey.Image}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Monkey.Name}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Monkey.Location}" FontSize="Micro"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Monkey.Details}" FontSize="Large"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

DetailsPage

```
  public partial class DetailsPage : ContentPage
{
    public DetailsPage(Monkey monkey)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

Comment: try using e.SelectedItem instead

Comment: same error opens only the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing everything good except that you forgot to reset the SelectedItem to null, that's why you are getting always the first list item clicked.

Your code should look like this:

```
async void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var monkey = e.SelectedItem as Monkey;

     if (monkey == null)
        return;

     await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(monkey)); // always await Navigations
     ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

P.S. Make your method async so you don't cause UI Thread to block

**EDIT**

Try to get the selected item from SelectedItemChangedEventArgs.

```
var monkey = e.SelectedItem as Monkey;
```

**UPDATE**

Okay the SelectedItem is being updated successfully but the 'Monkey Item' on the ViewModel behind the DetailsPage is not!

So on DetailsPage add this line:

```
public partial class DetailsPage : ContentPage
{
    public DetailsPage(Monkey monkey)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new DetailsViewModel(monkey); // Update the BindingContext
    }
}
```

And remove this line on the DetailsPage.xaml:

```
BindingContext="{x:Static design:ViewModelLocator.DetailsViewModel}"
```

Comment: The same error occurs, opens only the item from the first position

Comment: I made the change and raises the same error opens only the first item, the xaml can influence something, look at my above edit xaml

Comment: Can you edit your question with more code regarding your ListView implementation? There must be something else wrong in your code since this is working on my side...

Comment: @José please add the .cs class too

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-Monkeys/tree/master/Monkeys-CarouselView I'm following this example application